# Problemas ao mostrar duração em horas e minutos em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando calcular uma duração entre valores de uma coluna no meu banco de dados. O valor até que está sendo calculado corretamente, mas acontece que o formato de hora:minuto não está saindo da maneira esperada.

Supondo que no meu banco de dados eu tenha a primeira duração que é de 1:30 e a segunda duração que é de 2:30, totalizará 04:00 horas, porém o que sai para mim em tela é 4:0 desse formato, como posso resolver?

Segue abaixo parte do meu código que faz a operação:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT ass.Duracao, pa.horas_dadas, pa.Horas_restantes, pa.Qtd_horas, ass.ID_Aluno, ass.ID_Pacote, ass.ID_Aula, pa.id_alunos FROM Assiste ass JOIN pacotes pa ON pa.ID=ass.ID_Pacote WHERE ID_Aluno = $pegaid AND ID_Pacote = $pegaid_pacote AND Status_presence = 'Ativa'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
{ 
    $hora= $row['Duracao']; 
    $show_qtd_horas = $row['Qtd_horas']; 
    $hora1 = explode(":",$hora); 
    $min_hora1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60); 
    $total=$total+$min_hora1; 
} 

$hora = floor($total / 3600); 
$total = $total - ($hora * 3600); 
$min = floor($total / 60)/10; 
$min=str_replace(".","",$min);
$result_duracao=$hora.":".$min; 

if(strlen($min)==1)
{ 
    $min=$min."0"; 
} 

$update_pacotes = mysql_query("UPDATE pacotes SET horas_dadas='$result_duracao' WHERE id_alunos=$pegaid AND ID=$pegaid_pacote");

echo $result_duracao;
```

Comment: Como que está salvo a hora na coluna Duracao? já esta em algum formato? H:mm || segundos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
   { 
     $hora= $row['Duracao']; 
     $show_qtd_horas = $row['Qtd_horas']; 
     $hora1 = explode(":",$hora); 

     $min_hora1 = ($hora1[0] * 3600) + ($hora1[1] * 60); 
     $total=$total+$min_hora1; 
   } 
     $hora = floor($total / 3600); 
     $total = $total - ($hora * 3600); 
     $min = floor($total / 60)/10; 
     $min=str_replace(".","",$min);
     $result_duracao=$hora.":".$min; 
     if(strlen($min)==1){ 
        $result_duracao=$result_duracao."0"; 
     } 

      $testeHora = explode(":",$result_duracao);
      $lenHora= strlen($testeHora[0]);

      if($lenHora==1){ 
        $result_duracao="0".$result_duracao; 
      }
```

> 1: No seu código altere  `$min=$min."0";` para  `$result_duracao=$result_duracao."0";`
>
> 2: acrescente essas linhas no final do código antes do update.

```
 $testeHora = explode(":",$result_duracao);
 $lenHora= strlen($testeHora[0]);
    if($lenHora==1){ 
      $result_duracao="0".$result_duracao; 
    }
```

> que irá verificar se a parte da hora contém 1 ou 2 digitos. Caso tenha um digito irá concatenar com um 0 na frente.

Comment: Sua resposta foi a melhor, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se o calculo esta correto você pode usar uma função 'date' nativa do php para exibir no padrão correto.

```
echo date('H:i', strtotime($nomedavariavel));
```

veja o exemplo utilizando o seu código [no phpFiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/8t57-wcq9)

Comment: Nao dá porque preciso mandar o dado para o banco de dados

Comment: não é para exibir em tela, preciso que este dado seja atualizado no banco

Comment: Salva uma variável com o resultado exemplo: $variavel_bd = date('H:m', strtotime($result_duracao));

Comment: Obrigado, tudo resolvido por aqui